# How to avoid by in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

Is it possible to avoid by in this sentence:

> I think DM can work in fields like climate change and urban planning so, I want to learn about it **by** studying the bachelor of sciences.

[PS: DM= Digital Mechanims]

Comment: "studying the bachelor of sciences" isn't a valid sequence in English. Do you mean *studying **for** a Bachelor of Science*? Note that today you'd more likely be studying [*for a **BSc***,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+a+Bachelor+of+Science%2Cfor+a+BSc&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20Bachelor%20of%20Science%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20BSc%3B%2Cc0) rather than *for a **Bachelor of Science** [degree]*. But I can't see ***why*** you might want to avoid using ***by*** in your context, so I wouldn't bother about that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could replace 'by' with a comma:

> I think DM can work in fields like climate change and urban planning, so I want to learn about it, studying the bachelor of sciences.

Or, as 'studying' and 'learning' essentially mean the same thing you could make your sentence a lot more direct by saying:

> I think DM can work in fields like climate change and urban planning, so I want to study it for my Bachelor of Science degree.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "via" to replace "by".